# WebApi error logging with Unity after exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-sql, error-handling, unity-container

I have my WebApi controller setup like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/product")]
public class ProductController : BaseApiController
{
    private IProductService productService;

    public ProductController(IProductService productService, ILoggingService loggingService)
    : base(loggingService, "Product")
    {
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    [Route("")]
    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult UpdateValue(int productId, int value)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(productService.UpdateValue(productId, value, CurrentUser.GetUserInternalId()));
        }
        catch (AccessDeniedException ade)
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, new ErrorsListModel(new ResponseModel()) { Errors = ade.Errors });
        }
        catch (CustomException ce)
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new ErrorsListModel(new ResponseModel()) { Errors = ce.Errors });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            loggingService.SaveError(ex, _controllerName, "product", "updateValue");
        }

        return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new ErrorsListModel(new ResponseModel() { name = "db", message = "e_db_error" }));
    }
}
```

I'm using Unity to resolve dependencies:

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
{
     var container = new UnityContainer();

     container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor(typeof(DBDataContext)));

     container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
     container.RegisterType<DBDataContext>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());

     container.RegisterType<IProductService, ProductService>();
     container.RegisterType<ILoggingService, LoggingService>();

     GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

And all is working nicely until a db error occurs in ProductSerivce. The exception in handled by try-catch block and inside of my LoggingService the instance of DBDataContext is the same instance that threw the exception in ProductService so naturaly when i try to use it again, it's throwing the same exception again during SubmitChanges call inside LoggingService. What am i doing wrong? Should i change my whole exception handling method? Or is there a way to force Unity to resolve new instance of DBDataContext just for my LoggingService?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT.

Okay, i got it done, if anyone is interested, here's how my UnityConfig looks now:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor(typeof(DBDataContext)));

container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>("LogginDbContext", new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor(new DBDataContext()));

container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<ErrorLog>, GenericRepository<ErrorLog>>("LoggingRepository", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IUnitOfWork>("LogginDbContext")));

container.RegisterType<DBDataContext>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());

container.RegisterType<IProductService, ProductService>();

container.RegisterType<ILoggingService, LoggingService>(
            new InjectionConstructor(
                new ResolvedParameter<IUnitOfWork>("LogginDbContext"),
                new ResolvedParameter<IGenericRepository<ErrorLog>>("LoggingRepository")));

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

All i had to do, was to create named mapping for my IUnitOfWork which always get fresh instance of DataContext, create named mapping for IGenericRepository which uses this named IUnitOfWork and pass both of these to the constructor of my LoggingService and voila! Now my LoggingService always get it's own DBDataContext.

Comment: You can try the 'TransientLifetimeManager' for the DBDataContext. This should create a new instance of that class for every resolution done for that type... in other words, it should inject different instances of the DBDataContext into the ProductService and LoggingService...

You probably already seen this, but here is it anyway: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately i've tried it before and it's not working. Both services get the same instance of DBDataContext. I don't know, maybe i'm registering DBDataContext in wrong way? But it's rather simple example and yet it's still not working. Easiest way out of this is to pull out my logging service from Unity and instantiate it manualy but i don't want to do that.